# How to get a list of comments for a selected post in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I've created the sample rails app with a list of apps showing in a DataTable.  If I select one of the rows, I want the view of the post to then show a table with the list of comments for that post below it.  In the post controller, I have:

```
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The result of the above it to give an error that it can't find a comment with id = 1.

What I'm trying to do is end up with a list just like the index returns for the posts that I can use on the post.html.erb page to create the list.  What arguments do I use to collect the comments for the found post ( if they exist )?  The comments schema has a column named 'post_id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same id you receive in your action to retrieve both the post and its comments. This is wrong, that's just the post id. You can retrieve them using your post like this

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post.id)
end
```

or, better, if you have a `comments` association defined in your `Post` model

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  It is hard to find clear answers to many parts of RoR.  Appreciate you help.

Comment: Try this tutorial if you don't know it https://www.railstutorial.org/book